# Не подгружаются скрипты на сайте при переносе

Tags: браузер, header

Перенес сайт с одного хостинга на другой, но на новом хостинге, во всех скриптах, которые подгружаются аяксом, в консоли request headers пишет Provisional headers are shown. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй посмотреть через chrome://net-internals